# how do i improve my nlp model to classify 4 different mental illness?

Tags: nlp, svm, text-classification, tf-idf, bert-language-model

I have a dataset in csv containing 2 columns: 1 is the label which determines the type of mental illness of the patient and the other is the corresponding reddit posts from a certain time period of that user.
These are the total number of patients in each group of illness:

1. control:          3000
2. depression:       2118
3. bipolar:          1062
4. ptsd:              330
5. schizophrenia:     148

for starters I tried binary classification between my depression and bipolar patients. I used tfidf vectors and fed it into 2 different types of classifiers: MultinomialNB and SVM.
here is a sample of the code:
using MultinomialNB:

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),('clf', MultinomialNB()),])
text_clf = text_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

using SVM:

```
text_clf_svm = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),('clf-svm', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2',alpha=1e-3, random_state=42)),])
text_clf_svm = text_clf_svm.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

these are my results:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

 bipolar       0.00      0.00      0.00       304

depression     0.68      1.00      0.81       650

accuracy                           0.68       954


macro avg       0.34      0.50      0.41       954

weighted avg    0.46      0.68      0.55       954
```

The problem is the models are simply just predicting all the patients to be in the class of the larger data sample, in this case all are being predicted as depressed patients. I have tried using BERT as well but I get the same accuracy. I have read papers on them using LIWC lexicon, These categories include variables that characterize linguistic style as well as psychological aspects of language.
I don't understand if what I am doing is correct or is there a better way at classifying using NLP, if so please enlighten me.
Thanking anybody who comes across such a big post and shares their idea beforehand!

Comment: Open questions like this fit better on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/, because SO is more focused on the programming side. Quick observations: the data is slightly imbalanced, so if the classifier doesn't find enough good indicators in the features it's not surprising that it always predict the majority class. You could try resampling but it certainly wouldn't work because the problem is about the features: it's likely that there are too many features and they are not very discriminative, especially if the texts are small. It's certainly a very difficult task, because it's not sure...

Comment: ... at all that the text is significantly different between the two illnesses (let alone between the 5 categories). There are a few things that could be tried: first you would probably need to simplify the features, by discarding the rare words (it's just noise for the classifier). Second you could try looking into methods specific for stylometry, i.e. classification based on the author style rather than the content. For example there are works about classifying by gender or age group, this might be closer to what you're trying to obtain.